# Bonsai JS error

Tags: javascript, bonsaijs

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- <script src="bonsai.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/uxebu/bonsai/bonsai-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title> Testing </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script>
      bonsai.run(document.getElementById('test'),{
        url: 'main.js',
        width: 1260,
        height: 680
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The js (main.js):
//Globals

```
var screenWidth = 1260;
var screenHeight = 680;

var background = new Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight).fill('#d3d3d3').addTo(stage);

window.setInterval(function(){
  console.log('hi');
}, 100);
```

The error: 
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) I'm not really sure what could be going wrong here. It looks like the docs.

Comment: need to see your main.js code as well. Its not bonsai, its your main.js throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because when you are loading the `main.js` file via the script tag, `Rect` is not defined. You can delete the following line:

```
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Alternately, you can change your use of bonsai api to `code`:

```
bonsai.run(document.getElementById('test'),{
  code: function () {
   //your code inside main.js
  },
  width: 1260,
  height: 680
});
```